# Send separate emails to multiple recipients based on a condition - Wordpress form

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have little knowledge of Wordpress, PHP etc however, I have created a ‘quote’ form. Upon submitting this form, it needs to go to multiple suppliers as seperate emails based on a condition.

For example;

Let’s say my quote form is about socks. I have 10 companies. Some of those companies may supply red and blue socks, only red or only blue socks or neither.

If in the quote form the customer selects say blue socks and then clicks submit, I want a separate email to be sent to all the suppliers that do blue socks.

Most of the forms enable you to set a condition such as blue socks and then send to only 1 email that is specified but I can’t seem to find anything that automatically works out what suppliers it needs to go to and then also to multiple recipients as separate emails.

Thank you,

Holly

Answer (score 0):

You should have some sort of database in place where you could look up that association between the suppliers and what they supply.  While it is possible to hard-code those associations in PHP, it's not recommendable to do so, because it's much harder to maintain than a database.  If you're working with WordPress, you should already be connected to a MySQL database, so you should be able to create a new table there for this purpose.